# Display several polygons at once with matplotlib by getting Google Vision API data in the right format

Tags: matplotlib, polygon, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

My goal is to display several polygons at once (this is data I'm getting from Google Vision API).

I have a list of coordinates in this format:

```
lst_coord = [['(742,335),(840,334),(840,351),(742,352)'], ['(304,1416),(502,1415),(502,1448),(304,1449)']
```

Knowing that those are strings:

```
(742,548),(814,549),(814,563),(742,562)
<class 'str'>
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotpoly(coord,x,y):

    coord.append(coord[0])
    x, y = zip(*coord) 
    plt.plot(x,y)

for coord in lst_coord:
    plotpoly(coord,x,y)

plt.show()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I've tried quite a few different things. But I can't get it to work...

Bonus: My final goal is to display those polygons on a picture and I'm also struggling with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html#matplotlib-patches-polygon) patches, they will close automatically:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

lst_coord = [['(742,335),(840,334),(840,351),(742,352)'], ['(304,1416),(502,1415),(502,1448),(304,1449)']]
patches = []
for coord in lst_coord:
    patches.append(Polygon(eval(coord[0])))
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, fc='none', ec='red'))
ax.set_xlim(0,1000)
ax.set_ylim(0,1500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works great, thanks! What about if I want to draw each one of those two polygons in a different color?

Comment: you can set the color for each polygon in the for loop and then specify `match_original=True` in `PatchCollection`